# From a numerical spinbox how to prevent the user from typing no numbers in QML

Tags: qt, qml

Having a SpinBox that is supposed to have always numbers that can go from a minimum value to a maximum value how can we prevent the user from an editable spinbox to delete the numbers on it, and the result turns into an **empty** value, like we can see in the top `SpinBox`:

[image]

Im looking to prevent this from happening on a spinbox of the following type:

```
SpinBox {
editable: true
from:1
to:100
}
```

i already tried a lot of properties and none of them seem to work.

Comment: "how can we prevent the user from an editable spinbox to delete the numbers on it, and the result turns into this" I don't understand this question - the value in the image you show is within the valid range of 1 to 100. I think it would be better if you showed an image of the result that you're trying to avoid.

Comment: Try to be more specific.

Comment: @Luka yes the phrase is confuse. What i meant is the top spinbox that has an empty value, i dont want that to happen, but still i want the spinbox editable so the user can write the number he wants, but if he writes nothing i want a default value to appear

Comment: What about letting the user erase the number from the spinbox, but as soon as the focus changes to some other control the value of the spinbox should be validated. If the content is not valid you can write back the last valid value.

Comment: Hi @Ponzifex how can that be done in qml?

Comment: @Ngranja1512 , I have created an answer to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have found a QML bug. `SpinBox` supposed to validate its value within the `from`-`to` range, but it is not happening every time. Here is a crude workaround which involves timer and will write the value into the `SpinBox` thus forcing to validate its value over and over again when no active focus present. If you have a lot of SpinBoxes, you may consider increasing the interval value of the timer in order to avoid performance degradation.

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("SpinBox bug workaround")

    function fixSpinBox(sb)
    {
        if(!sb.activeFocus) {
            var tmp = sb.value
            sb.value = sb.from
            sb.value = sb.to
            sb.value = tmp
        }
    }

    Timer {
        interval: 250; running: true; repeat: true
        onTriggered: {
            fixSpinBox(sb1)
            fixSpinBox(sb2)
        }
    }

    Column {
        SpinBox {
            id: sb1
            from: 1
            to: 100
            editable: true
        }
        SpinBox {
            id: sb2
            from: 1
            to: 100
            editable: true
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to disable input.
See "editable": https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-spinbox.html